# State “i” goes to state “j”: list accessible states in a Markov-chain

Tags: markov-chains

I would like to have a code that given a state "i" in S, it give the set of states "j" which are accessible from "i".

Is that possible in mathematica?

My state space (S) is

```
StateSpace = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"}
```

and my transition matrix is

```
transitionmatrix = {{17/25, 3/25, 5/25, 0, 0}, {5/18, 5/18, 7/18, 1/18, 0}, {4/21,  
9/21, 4/21, 0, 4/21}, {0, 0, 3/4, 1/4, 0}, {3/4, 1/4, 0, 0, 0}}
```

And i know that a state "i" goes to "j" if in the transition matrix the value (i,j) is higher than zero.

I would like something like this

```
If[transitionmatrix {i, j} > 0, t];
```

And then i will have

```
transitionmatrix{1,2}
true
```

(as 1 goes to 2)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This uses `Pick` twice, once to select rows of the transition matrix, and again to select elements of the state space corresponding to positive elements of the matrix:

```
accessibleStates[i_] := Union@Flatten[
   Pick[StateSpace, #, _?Positive] & /@ 
    Pick[transitionmatrix, StateSpace, i]]

accessibleStates["4"]
(* {"3", "4"} *)
```

You can use patterns, e.g.

```
accessibleStates["1" | "4"]
(* {"1", "2", "3", "4"} *)
```

Comment: Thanks exactly what i wanted :D really helpfull

Comment: but i'm not understanding what the second one does (accessibleStates["1" | "4"])

Comment: I would guess it means states accessible from either 1 or 4.

Comment: @MarianadaCosta, the symbol `|` is a shorthand for `Alternatives`, so as Paxinum said, `"1"|"4"` is a pattern which matches either `"1"` or `"4"`. You may have no use for this, but I thought it worth mentioning.

Comment: oh right, thanks (:

Answer (score 0):

As labelled fits with Mma 'natural' labeling. So,

```
fun[m_, i_] := Catenate@Position[Unitize@m[[i]], 1]
```

e.g.

```
Grid[Prepend[{#, fun[transitionmatrix, #]} & /@ Range[5], {"Vertex", 
   "Adjacent Out-vertices"}], Frame -> {True, True}, 
 Dividers -> {All, {True, True, {False}, True}}]
```

[image]

Note also: `DiscreteMarkovProcess`:

```
dm = DiscreteMarkovProcess[
  1, {{17/25, 3/25, 5/25, 0, 0}, {5/18, 5/18, 7/18, 1/18, 0}, {4/21, 
    9/21, 4/21, 0, 4/21}, {0, 0, 3/4, 1/4, 0}, {3/4, 1/4, 0, 0, 0}}]
g=Graph[dm]
MarkovProcessProperties[dm]
```

[image]